# PyQt5 | Как сделать консоль, а так же как сделать так что-бы в неё выводились print input

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Всем привет, давно хотел написать консоль но так ни разу и не получилось, как бы сделать так чтобы в окно pyqt5 выводились print а также input, или как сделать что-то на подобии вывода в консоль?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите пример с нормальным виджетом тут

https://github.com/lxqt/qtermwidget/blob/master/examples/pyqt/main.py

Написать  свой с поддержкой инпут и принт сделать не сложно, но тогда нужны подробности что в этом терминале будет жить.

Comment: Спасибо, но теперь возник вопрос как же организовать эти самые print input

Comment: И как через pip установить QTermWidget

Comment: и в теменале будут жить свои программы, как проверить ввод в input? который я создать должен

Comment: Через pip наверное никак. Это плагин qt.

Comment: Свои программы... Ну если самое простое, то sys.executable подсунуть вместо vim в примере.

Comment: а как через qt я так не делал ещё

Comment: не программы а команды L1meek#6047, могу в дс дать подробности

Comment: Команды тоже можно завернуть, но это муть с тредами.... Проще отдельный процесс там запускать) в случе если нет взаимодействия ни с чем в окне кроме терминала

Comment: Я в дискорд не умею. Пиши тут. Начни с ОС на которой это должно запуститься

Comment: наверное будет лучше самому написать

Comment: думаю лучше использовать другой способ, я сказал что-то на подобии консоли, а значит не обязательно заморачиватся